# Exercise 2.17: Algebraic curves - William Fulton

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $V=V(Y^2-X^2(X+1))\subset\mathbb{A}^2$, e $\overline{X}, \overline {Y}$ the residues of $X,Y$ in $A(V)$ its coordinate ring; let $z= \dfrac{\overline{Y}}{\overline{X}}\in K(V)$. Find the pole sets of $z$ and of $z^2$.

I know that $z^2$ has no poles, it is polynomial. I know that points of the form $(0,y)$ where $y\neq 0$ are pole, and points of the form $(x,0)$, where $x\neq 0$ $x\neq −1$. I do not know if these are all poles. There are other poles ?

Answer (score 5):

The pole set of $z$ is $\{ (0,0)\}$.

Let $J_z = \{ G\in k[X,Y]| \overline G z \in A(V) \}$.

Claim that: $J_z = (X,Y).$

$J_z \subset (X,Y)$ is trivial. To see that $(X,Y) \subset J_z$, it suffices to check that $\overline X z = \overline Y  \in A(V)$ and $\overline Y z =  {\overline {X^2(X+1)}}/{\overline X} = \overline {X(X+1)} \in A(V)$.

Then the pole set of $z$ is $V(J_z) = \{ (0,0)\}$.

Comment: How did you think that $J_{f}$ could be $<X,y>$?

Comment: Why is $J_z\subseteq(X,Y)$ trivial? I thought that was the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I am not able to comment now. But I will answer the question posted by Jackozee Hakkiuz under the answer of Ire Shaw.

As is shown in the answer of Ire Shaw, we have $(X,Y)\subseteq J_z$. Since $(X,Y)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[X,Y]$, we must have $J_z=(X,Y)$ or $J_z=k[X,Y]$. In the latter case, we have, in particular, $1\in J_z$, which means $\frac{X}{Y}\in\Gamma(V)$, which can be shown to be a contradiction (without difficulty)! So $J_z$ is forced to be $(X,Y)$.